# RegEx - Replace all but the first match

Tags: regex

How can I use RegEx within a replace function, applied to a string, to match all instances of a substring, except for the first one?

e.g. if I am replacing all 'a' except the first and my string is:

```
a b a c b a a b
```

I want to get:

```
a b c b b
```

---

My actual use case is that I am building a project using Ant, which is concatenating a bunch of .js files into one. Each javascript file starts with: "use strict". I only want this declaration once, thus I wish to remove all instances of this substring, except the one at the start.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general regex:

```
echo "a b a c b a a b" | perl -pWe 's/(?<=(a))(.*?)\1/$2/g'
```

It uses lookbehind to check if the matched pattern is first in the string.
(Basically, what I had in mind was `s/(?<=(a).*?)\1//g`, but variable-length lookbehind does not seem to be widely implemented).
There is a drawback - it will produce output like

```
a b  c b   b
```

To make it tidy, you can use

```
echo "a b a c b a a b" | perl -pWe 's/(?<=(a\s))(.*?)\1/$2/g'
```

but it wouldn't remove last `a` in input like `a b a c b a a`

Comment: Although this works great in perl, it appears that lookbehind assertions are not supported by Ant's replaceregexp: `The value of attribute &quot;match&quot; associated with an element type &quot;null&quot; must not contain the '&lt;' character.`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all the occurrences of `"use strict";` and then add one at the start again.

**Edit**: Examples:

1. ```
   sed '/"use strict";/d' < infile > outfile
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   (echo '"use strict"'; sed '/"use strict";/d') < infile > outfile
   ```
2. ```
   perl -nie 'print unless /"use strict";/;' file
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   perl -nie 'BEGIN { print qq["use strict";\n]; } print unless /"use strict";/;' file
   ```

Comment: I did consider this but I have no idea how to prepend a substring to a file using Ant without wastefully making a temp copy of the file. I also thought adding this constraint to RegEx would be simple...

Answer (score 0):

To solve your example, you could use a negative lookahead assertion:

```
echo "a b a c b a a b" | perl -pe 's/(?!^)a //g'
```

Results:

```
a b c b b
```

To solve your project problem (assuming `use strict` does not occur multiple times on each line in your concatenated file), you could use `GNU sed` to remove every occurrence except the first:

```
sed '0,/$/!s/use strict//g' file.txt
```